# How to display a the R Code and output separately in a Rmarkdown PDF

Tags: rstudio

While knitting the RMarkdown, the code and Output looks so messy. Trying to separate the code and output for better Rmarkdown display.

New to RSTUDIO, No idea.

I need to have a minimum 220 characters, so anything here is just to fill up the text box.

Comment: `knitr` options https://yihui.org/knitr/options/ might help. Especially `eval` and `echo`.